# I would like to understand this shell script

Tags: linux, bash

This is an assignment I received.

I have been requested to explain what the purpose of this code is. However, when I execute this, there does not appear any output.

As I am new to shell scripting, could somebody help me out?

Thanks a lot.

```
#!/bin/bash
# $1 = node IP
# $2 = node port
# $3 = hostname to resolve

[[ $# != 3 ]] && logger -p local0.error -t ${0##*/} -- "usage: ${0##*/} <node IP> <node port> <hostname to resolve>" && exit 1
node_ip=$(echo $1 | sed 's/::ffff://')
dig +short @$node_ip $3 IN A &> /dev/null
[[ $? == 0 ]] && echo “UP”
```

Comment: If you call the script without parameters, the usage message does not go to console, but to the syslog. It seems this script just passes 2 of the 3 parameters to [`dig`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dig), and if the call is successful, it echoes "UP" (you may have to correct the quotes around "UP").

Comment: "this is the assignment ***I*** have given been to tell working of this code" - will you be getting others to do your work for you when you enter the workforce? If not, I'd suggest learning to do your own work ASAP, the last thing we need are *more* cowboys :-)

Answer (score 2):

`$#`: number of parameters passed to your script, if you execute this script like this: `bash filename.sh p1 p2 p3 p4`, the `$#` in the `filename.sh` will be evaluated to `4`

`$?`: return value of the previous command. In shell, return value of non-zero means something wrong happened.

`[[ $# != 3 ]] && logger ... && 1`: means if the amount of parameters is not 3, then log something and exit with return value 1

`node_ip=$(echo $1 | sed 's/::ffff://')`: replace the `::ffff:` in the first parameter and assign it to `node_ip`

`dig +short @$node_ip $3 IN A &> /dev/null`: call `dig` command and redirect the output to `/dev/null`, so you can't see any thing printed out. By the way, I don't know what `dig` does

`[[ $? == 0 ]] && echo “UP”`: if `dig` command (namely the previous command) returns a zero value, which means SUCCESS, then print the word `UP`

Comment: I took the liberty to edit and add code formatting to the command names, filename and regular expression. Good job.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin why you can edited my answer?

Comment: @ddwolf because I have the ability to improve the formatting of your answer to include the code formatting that you forgot to include.